# Should the foil face on Iso foam board house wrap face in or out?

Tags: insulation

Should the foil face on Iso foam board house wrap face in or out? I want to use 2 layers for an R value outside of 15 or more. This may be a moot point since the foam board I was using just went up in cost by 50%, but I have 22 sheets of it that I intend to use. 1-1/2" Johns Manfield iso, R 9.8

I may go to used Iso since it is much cheaper and apparently broken in so the R value has settled to its final value.

Any advice on which way to face? Tight to sheathing or facing out under vinyl siding? or both - inner layer in, outer layer out?

Comment: I'm curious... how does foam "break in" and "settle to its final value"? Do you have some references where I could read up on this?

Comment: Depends. Where do you want the heat and air to be? The foil is reflective of radiant heat and stops drafts. You haven't told us much about your climate or overall home structure.

Comment: @FreeMan, my understanding is that the chemical they use to bubble the foam has better insulation properties than air. My understanding is that as diffusion dilutes this gas over a years-long time horizon, the R-value equilibrates to an air based value that is less than the marketed one. I assumed this was the "settling" he was talking about.

Comment: Please take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers.

Answer (score 0):

Point the outermost panel's foil outward if you've got air movement between it and the siding. Otherwise it doesn't matter.

Aluminum reflects IR radiation pretty well. That's what the foil layer is doing. Without an air gap it doesn't work, though (a building official will probably include its R value even if it's not doing anything). If you're tightly stacking insulation panels with foil bearing tight against any surface, then read some fine print to discover the R value(s) that need subtracting from the assembly's rating.

With the typical installation pattern of tight-to-wall-sheathing, the foil can only reflect heat outward (when it's correctly oriented). It doesn't reflect heat back into the house. This implies that there's some break even point where you don't want active foil. If the foil reflects away a lot of wanted IR during cold winter months, then active foil could be counterproductive depending on the mildness of your summers.

Comment: Thank you. It's what I thought. However, I don't understand why foil doesn't reflect radiation without an air gap. Any answers from the laws of thermodynamics to explain this?

Comment: Maybe it's just not measurable thru wood.

Comment: @Dr.Jazz, I'm basically just repeating somebody else's authority, but my rationalization has always been that the heat diffuses from surface to surface when there's no gap (any reflected IR would heat the adjacent surface, so it's still free to diffuse). Of course "zero" is probably too strong of a claim, but I imagine that it's effectively zero given the total lack of equivocation in how I've seen it discussed.

Comment: @Dr.JazzBass if you'll please take the [tour], you'll note that the proper way to say "thanks" is to click the up vote arrow on answers that help you and the check mark on the ones that provide the solution to your question.